# Why is it passing the console.log as argiment of the Observble subscribe() function?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, angular-observable

I am pretty new in Angular and functional programming and I have a doubt about this syntax (that I think should be related to functional programming behavior):

```
courses$: Observable<{}[]>;
.................................
.................................
.................................
this.courses$.subscribe(console.log);
```

So **courses$** should be an array of **Observable** (what exactly means the **<{}[]>** syntax?)

The last line seems to print into the JavaScript console the subscribed content. But what exactly means this syntax? I know that **console.log()** is a function that take as argument the value that have to be print. Why in this case it is as argiment of the subscribe function and it doesn't end with ()?

Comment: `Observable<{}[]>` means it is an `Observable` of plain obects array i.e. `[{},{},{}]` for example

Answer (score 2):

To maybe understand it better: In JavaScript functions are first class objects, which means they can be treated as ordinary variables, passed as arguments, altered, or deleted. Take a look at this:

```
something => console.log(something)
```

As you see, this is a function that logs something to the console. And what is `console.log`? Well, it's a function that logs something to the console, no different!

Consider this **pseudocode**:

```
Observable.prototype.subscribe = function(callback) {
   // every time a new value is emitted 
   callback(newValue);
}
```

Of course, this is not how the `.subscribe` method is implemented actually, but this is essentially what it does: when an observable receives a new piece of data, it will call the callback you have provided, passing the `next` value as the first argument to that callback. Hope this clears things for you.

Answer (score 1):

It's passing `console.log`, the function reference, into `subscribe`. Subscribe will call that function, later, when the subscription publishes. The argument(s) it passes are determined by subscribe, at the point it fires. This is simply passing a callback function into subscribe.

Comment: Further, if you passed in `console.log()`, you'd be executing that function and passing in its result instead of a reference to the function itself.

Comment: Subscribe will call that function later, when the observable calls the **next** function. It will not be called on `complete` or `error`, that is what parameters 2 and 3 of the `subscribe` method are for

Answer (score 1):

`subscribe` accepts a function as an argument of the type `(parameter: T) => void`, where T is the template of `Observable<T>`.

these three work similarly:

```
this.courses$.subscribe(console.log);
this.courses$.subscribe(function (p: {}[]): void { console.log(p); });
this.courses$.subscribe((p: {}[]): void => console.log(p));
```

there are a few differences of captured variables and scopes between each type of function declaration, but on this particular example they work the same.